# Why does video conversion make my video look like an old movie?

Tags: video, conversion, youtube

I have downloaded some videos from you tube of a boxing match. It looks fine on You tube. After I download and convert the video, the sudio is fine and matches the video but the actual video looks like an old silent film in that the motionis not fluid, seems to be a little jerky, like an old silent movie. What coudl I do to improve the end result?

I down load the files, they are flv, then I convert them to mp4, then burn them out with Movie Factory 7.

Please let me know if you have any ideas thanks.

Answer (score 0):

What converter program are you using to convert the video? Make sure that your output FPS is at least 24 or near. Your converter maybe outputting the video at a low FPS by default, the reason for the non-fluid motion. Also make sure you're setting a good bit rate for the output.

Some easy to use free programs:

- Any Video Converter http://www.filehippo.com/download_any_video_converter/
- Format Factory http://www.formatoz.com/